# Applescript variable path to the mail attachments

Tags: applescript

I am trying to send attachments via Mail App and have a list of file names without extension in the source text file. Each line will be looped until all lines in the text file finished.

How do I make a path for the attachment using looped lines of the source text and add the extension to the end?

This is what I use to read the lines from the text file and loop them

```
set lns to paragraphs of (read file srcFile as «class utf8»)
repeat with ln in lns
```

This is what the send attachment part of the script look

```
set theAttachmentFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:attachmentfolder" + ln + ".pdf"
```

The above is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your text file contains only file name without path and extension, I assume that the folder path where these files are stored is known before in the script: correct ?

About extension, it is much easier to store it also in the text file for 2 reasons : if you don't, you need to get every file whose name contains "xxx", and cross your fingers that you find one an only one file. if there are 2 files with same title but different extension...you can't select !

The script for creating new email and add attachment should be :

```
Tell Application "Mail"
Set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:My_Subject, content:My_Content}
tell newMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"", address:send_to_addr}
    make new attachment with properties {file name:TheAttachmentFile} at after the last paragraph
end tell
end tell
```